# Generic absolute value function

Tags: c++, c++14

I wanted to write a generic `abs` function that would correctly work for every type. Basically, I wanted to use the following algorithm:

- If the type is a built-in integer, use `std::abs` from `<cstdlib>`.
- If the type is a built-in floating-point, use `std::abs` from `<cmath>.`
- If the type is a user-defined type with a namespace-level `abs`, use it.
- Otherwise, call a generic `abs` algorithm.

Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace math
{
    namespace detail
    {
        // generic abs algorithm
        template<typename T>
        constexpr auto abs(const T& value)
            -> T
        {
            return (T{} < value) ? value : -value;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto abs(const T& value)
        -> T
    {
        using std::abs;
        using detail::abs;
        return abs(value);
    }
}
```

The idea is to create a generic `detail::abs` algorithm, then to create another `abs` function that will choose the function to call thanks to the argument-dependant lookup. Here is what I tried to take into account:

- While the generic algorithm also works for built-in integral and floating point types, `std::abs` may produce optimized code for these types. Using `std::abs` when possible will probably generate an optimized executable. That said, `std::abs` lacks `constexpr`, which is a desirable feature, and the compiler might recognize a absolute value-like construct and optimize it away...
- Some types have a namespace-level `abs` that does not behave like the generic algorithm. Therefore, we have to call this namespace-level function if it exist.
- Some types may be huge. Therefore, I chose to take the parameter by `const&` since some namespace-level `abs` may also take their parameter by `const&`.
- Some types only provide `operator<` to represent the ordering, but not the other relational operators. Therefore, calling `operator<` in the generic algorithm is more likely to work.
- I chose to use `T{}` instead of `0` for the comparison in the generic algorithm in order to be able to represent the default value for any given type. A type is not guaranteed to be comparable to an integer.

Here is a test case to demonstrate what the function can achieve (you can also test it [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecb83dadd8d81e89)):

> ```
> namespace eggs
> {
>     struct Foo
>     {
>         Foo(int val):
>             val(val)
>         {}
>
>         int val;
>     };
>
>     Foo abs(Foo foo)
>     {
>         return { std::abs(foo.val) };
>     }
> }
>
> struct Bar
> {
>     Bar(int val=0):
>         val(val)
>     {}
>
>     Bar operator-() const
>     {
>         return { -val };
>     }
>
>     int val;
> };
>
> bool operator<(const Bar& lhs, const Bar& rhs)
> {
>     return lhs.val < rhs.val;
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     using namespace std::literals;
>
>     std::cout << math::abs(-5) << '\n';
>     std::cout << math::abs(-5.3f) << '\n';
>     std::cout << math::abs(-5i+2.0) << '\n';
>
>     eggs::Foo foo = { -8 };
>     std::cout << math::abs(foo).val << '\n';
>
>     Bar bar = { -9 };
>     std::cout << math::abs(bar).val << '\n';
> }
> ```

What do you think of such a function? Did I miss any obscure error? Do you see anything that could be improved (in the implementation, I don't care about the test case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you have a bug in your generic implementation, especially in relation to floating-point style classes that [have signed-zero values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero):

your code:

```
return (T{} < value) ? value : -value;
```

would be better as a `T{} <= value` (or rewritten as `(T{} > value) ? -value : value;`).

Your current logic will return `-0.0` for an input value of `0.0`, and that's not appropriate for an `abs()` function.

Additionally, I don't know how you would really test these things, because, if I am not mistaken, in floating-point comparisons with signed-zero values, `-0.0 == 0.0` yet I would expect that `abs(-0.0)` would return `0.0`.

How you resolve this issue though, I don't know.

Comment: That's actually a question: if it is not observable, does it matter?

Comment: @Morwenn It's observable. To test, divide by zero! `1.0 / 0.0` is `inf`. `1.0 / -0.0` is `-inf`.

Comment: @200_success You're right. I'm not used to handling floating point issues. I almost never run into problems, so that's something that I generally don't even take into account (and that's a shame). That said, floating point values are handled by `std::abs` and not by the generic algorithm. Therefore, I don't think that I have a bug.

Comment: @Morwenn - you will still be negating any value/class that presents as `==` to `T{}`. It would be safer to only negate those strictly less than  `T{}`

Comment: @JerryCoffin - the point is that an input value of `0.0` is not `>` than `0.0`, so, the code as presented by Morwenn, will return `-0.0` ... which is odd, for a function called `abs()`. Changing the operator to `<=` instead of `<` is all that I am suggesting.

Comment: Hm...good point. Traditionally, you only require `<` to be defined, so you'd want to switch the order of operands rather than the operator though. `return a < T{} ? -a : a;`

Comment: @JerryCoffin I am almost ashamed of not having thought of a solution that simple. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4):

The only point I'd make it to look into using `boost::call_traits` ( see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) ). Instead of always passing by `const T&`, this will select the "best" way to pass a parameter: by `const T` for small, built in types (such as `int`), and by `const T&` for class types.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto abs(boost::call_traits<T>::param_type value)
    -> T
{ ... }
```